# How to store and retrieve value of enum with ServiceStack ICacheClient backed by Redis

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, redis, servicestack

I am using the ICacheClient and Redis to cache values in my app.

In one case, I need to cache the value of a enum.

The enum looks like this

```
public enum Status
{
    OK,
    Warn,
    Error
}
```

I am adding the value to the cache as such:

```
cacheClient.Add<Status>(myKey, Status.Warn);
```

When I go to retrieive the value like this:

```
Status status;
status = cacheClient.Get<Status>(myKey);
```

An exception is throw because the value returned by the cache client does not match an enum value.

I seem to be getting a value back that has escaped `"` marks like: `\"Warn\"`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which version of ServiceStack are you using? Seems to work for me on 3.9.42.0. The cache stores the string data as JSON so it could be related to this issue with ServiceStack.Text which was recently closed - https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/issues/242

Comment: Thanks @passchpa , upgrading to .42.0 seems to have been the fix. Submit this as the answer and I will mark as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix seems to be using ServiceStack version 3.9.42.0 or greater. The cache stores the string data as JSON so the issue is likely related to [this fix](http://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/issues/242) with ServiceStack.Text which was recently closed.